# ListenableFutureTask / ExecutorService

Tags: java, guava, executorservice

I've Guava in my Classpath and want to use `ListenableFuture`s, but currently I don't know how to submit `ListenableFuture`s or is it currently only possible to use them without an executor in the calling thread? I've read that a decorator is available in r10 which isn't out?

I've found `Futures.makeListenable(Future<V> future)` but I'm not sure if that's currently the only way how to use `ListenableFuture`s.

kind regards,
Johannes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We improved the `ListenableFuture` Javadoc for the forthcoming r10, including adding information about how to obtain an instance of the class.  You can see the HEAD version here: http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/ListenableFuture.html

The decorator method you're interested in is [MoreExecutors.listeningDecorator](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/MoreExecutors.html#listeningDecorator%28java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService%29)

Comment: Thanks Chris, I'm using `Futures.makeListenable(Future<V> future)` until r10 is available (via Maven ;-)). I'm using it in a loop though I think it's **not** ugly to use the static wrapper method. At first I just couldn't find the meantioned `ListenableExecutorService` or the appropriate method. Thanks again.